Google Maps Distance Matrix API returing empty "destination_addresses" and no distance data
I've got a list of addresses without city or zip, but in the vicinity of another address. The Google Distance Matrix API is generally able to infer the locale of the destination address from that of the origin address. For example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=818 Oklahoma Blvd, Alva, OK 73717&destinations=889 W Lakes Dr&key=<key>

returns JSON that starts with:
{
   "destination_addresses" : 
   [
      "889 W Lakes Dr, Alva, OK 73717, USA"

and gives me distance data, along with elements status "OK".
But for many addresses, the JSON comes out with destination_addresses empty. For example, for the address, 1007 Mill St, which I've linked to Google Maps to show the address exists in the same zip code, when I ask the API:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=818 Oklahoma Blvd, Alva, OK 73717&destinations=1007 Mill St&key=<key>

it returns JSON that starts with:
{
   "destination_addresses" : 
   [
      ""

and no distance data, along with elements status "NOT_FOUND".
This is happening for about a third of my addresses. Is there a reason Google is failing on them, even though they are valid addresses near the origin address? Is there a way to get Google to return the correct data for them?

Could someone say why the close vote? Is this not a legitimate problem?

Google expects valid addresses. A street name + number without zip code, city and/or country are very likely ambiguous.

I found a workaround that works most of the time.
For my list of addresses, I don't know the city or zip codes, but I do know they are all in the same county. I found that if I append the county and state to the street address in the query, then Google returns a good result most of the time. So, in the example above, when I changed the query to:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=818 Oklahoma Blvd, Alva, OK 73717&destinations=1007 Mill St, Woods County, OK&key=<key>

the JSON response started with:
{
   "destination_addresses" : 
   [
      "1007 Mill St, Alva, OK 73717, USA"

and it gave me distance data and elements status "OK".
I still wonder why Google was able to infer the locale for most of the destinations from the nearby origin addresses, but not able to do it for a lot of them. If anyone has an insight on why that was happening, that would be a better answer than this one.
